# display single values from mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, database

i know this is a noob question but please bear with me,

i am trying to display a single cell value from a table.

the table is named game-ships and contains fields populated with users info such as;

ship_id , ship_name, login_id , login_name , clan_id , location

stuff like that.

i need to find out where a given users ships are,
i cant do this with an array i need to display single values on boxes.

something in the lines of

display a particular user's ships and locations in a way that would be....

display user's ships || display user's ships location,

preferably with a link but its fine without.

This information is to be displayed in small boxes on top of the user's screen thats why i need separate boxes.

Thank you for reading this message and helping.

Answer (score 0):

can u provide the explanation with sample data.Below is the way according to my understanding :

select ship_name,location 
from game-ships
where login_id = 'login_user_id' // this will give you the name,location of the ship of the login user

Comment: well, ship name is generally a name, ex. test, ship location is a number, ex 136.  since a user can have more than one ship its becomes hard for him/her to keep track of them. hence, i need to bring this info to facilitate navigation through ships and locations. im unable to test the info you posted here but ill post here and answer as soon as i test it. .... one more thing, since i need to display the sip name and respective location separate, would i have to make a conection to the database for each field? or just one on the top of the page?

Comment: every ship has a unique ship id that identifies it as a ship, along with a lifetime info, how many kills, how many fighters, present location etc.

Comment: foreach($ships as $ship) { echo $ship->ship_name . ' || ' . $ship->location; }since u need to display the sip name and respective location separate,u would not have to make a conection to the database for  the above mine query will help u & & later u have to iterate thru the array .

Answer (score 0):

So what's the problem with arrays?
First you select the data ('ship_id, ship_name, location'), then fetch it into the $ships array.
Then you just iterate over it and display in a way you want.

```
foreach($ships as $ship)
{
 echo $ship['ship_name'] . ' || ' . $ship['location'];
}
```

One more thing. Maybe I just got it wrong, but to allow user to have several ships, you need to modify your database structure. You need a one-to-many relation. It means, that you should split your table. So you'll have a **user** table with **id, login, clan_id** and a **ship** table with **id, user_id, name, location** which refers to the **user**

**edited**

Array is array. It's just data and does not show up by itself. Sending it to the browser is your job. You need to iterate over it and print the rows->fields that you want.

For example, you got 3 user's ships from the database. To print only the last ship's name, you would

```
echo ships[2]['ship_name'];
```

Comment: well my understanding is that the array will display the information in a table automatically, im trying to display the data as compact as i can to fit a mobile, screen. .... users already have more than one ship, problem spawns when they navigate from a location to another leaving ships along the way and forgetting where they left them.

Comment: my codebase and php system is already built, it would not be practical to modify almost 60 pages to the split updates and such, its very clever though.

Answer (score 0):

After the execution of the query add this,

foreach($mysql_result as $ship_info) 
{ echo$ship_info->ship_name . ' || ' . $ship_info->location; }                              since u need to display the ship name and respective location separate,u would not have to make a conection to the database for  the above query will help u & & later u have to iterate thru the array as mentioned

Comment: ok, i am trying it the really noob way however i am not getting any results..... this is what im trying so far...........<?php

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

$dbname = 'name';
mysql_select_db($dbname);
   
$sql = "SELECT `ship_name` FROM `game_ships` WHERE `login_name` = \'user\' LIMIT 0, 30 ";

?>

Comment: try to echo the $sql & copy the result & try to run in phpmydmin. You will come to know whether the Query is right & if the query is right , Is it returning the result.TRY  IT OUT

Comment: try to echo the $sql & copy the result & try to run in phpmydmin. You will come to know whether the Query is right & if the query is right , Is it returning the result.I think the user value is not taken as you have put between the '' quotes.you nee to use something like this=> $sql = "SELECT ship_name FROM game_ships WHERE login_name ='".user."' "; bcoz "user" variable will not be executed as a PHP code. TRY  IT OUT